# Scikit-learn MLPRegressor - How not to predict negative results?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, regression, prediction

I was trying to train and test my dataset using MLPRegressor. I have two datasets (train dataset and test dataset), both of them have the exact same columns of features and label. Here's the example of my datasets :

```
Full,Id,Id & PPDB,Id & Words Sequence,Id & Synonyms,Id & Hypernyms,Id & Hyponyms,Gold Standard
1.667,0.476,0.952,0.476,1.429,0.952,0.476,2.345
3.056,1.111,1.667,1.111,3.056,1.389,1.111,1.9
1.765,1.176,1.176,1.176,1.765,1.176,1.176,2.2
0.714,0.714,0.714,0.714,0.714,0.714,0.714,0.0
................
```

here's my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

randomseed = np.random.seed(0)

datatraining = pd.read_csv("datatrain.csv")

datatesting = pd.read_csv("datatest.csv")

columns = ["Full","Id","Id & PPDB","Id & Words Sequence","Id & Synonyms","Id & Hypernyms","Id & Hyponyms"]

labeltrain = datatraining["Gold Standard"].values
featurestrain = datatraining[list(columns)].values


labeltest = datatesting["Gold Standard"].values
featurestest = datatesting[list(columns)].values

X_train = featurestrain
y_train = labeltrain

X_test = featurestest
y_test = labeltest

mlp = MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', hidden_layer_sizes=50, max_iter=1000, learning_rate='constant', random_state=randomseed)

mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Accuracy training : {:.3f}'.format(mlp.score(X_train, y_train)))
print

predicting = mlp.predict(X_test)
print predicting
print
```

And here's the result of the prediction :

```
[ 1.97553444  3.43401776  3.04097607  2.7015464   2.03777686  3.63274593
  3.37826962 -0.60260337  0.41626517  3.5374289   3.66114929  3.244683
  2.6313756   2.14243075  3.20841434  2.105238    4.9805092   4.00868273
  2.45508505  4.53332828  3.41862096  3.35721078  3.23069344  3.72149434
  4.9805092   2.61705563  1.55052494 -0.14135979  2.65875196  3.05328206
  3.51127424  0.51076396  2.39947967  1.95916595  3.71520651  2.1526807
  2.26438616  0.73249057  2.46888695  3.56976227  1.03109988  2.15894353
  2.06396103  0.66133707  4.72861602  2.4592647   2.84176811  2.3157664
  1.68426416  2.56022955 -0.00518545  1.67213609  0.6998739   3.25940136
  3.25369266  3.88888542  1.9168694   2.26036302  3.97917769  2.00322903
  3.03121106  3.29083723  0.6998739   4.33375678  0.6998739   2.71141538
 -4.23755447  3.958574    2.67765274  2.68715423  2.32714117  2.6500056
  ........]
```

As we can see, there are some negative results. How not to predict negative results? Besides, my datasets are contain of all positive values.

Comment: You need to impose positivity restrictions in one way or another on predicted values. So you may want to turn your question from *Why does it show negative results* into *How not to predict negative results*, or more generally, into *How to constrain the domain of prediction*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no categorical variables. Also, you mentioned in the question that you have all positive values. 
Try to standardize your data using `SatandardSacler()`. Use your X_train and y_train to [standardize](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler) data.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing as pre
...
scaler = pre.StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
```

After initializing the model with best parameters based on your case, `fit` scaled data,

```
mlp.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
...
predicting = mlp.predict(X_test_scaled)
```

This should do it. Let me know how it goes.

Also, there are some good reads,

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189652/is-it-a-good-practice-to-always-scale-normalize-data-for-machine-learning
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7757/data-normalization-and-standardization-in-neural-networks

Answer (score -3):

Add a second hidden layer with one ReLU node.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Consider reading this instruction [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)